# How to copy all folders at a certain level, but no files or subfolder?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I would like to know how to copy all folders to a new location, but I want only to include the folders themselves -- nothing that is inside of them (so, no subfolders, and no files).  Is this possible?

Also, related to this, is there also a way to copy all folders, and also subfolders within those folder, but only 1-level deep (so only direct child folders, not children within the children), and still without any files copied.

I'm open to doing this in any way -- command line, or via a utility.

Answer (score 8):

Use the Microsoft utility `robocopy`.

```
robocopy SOURCE_FOLDER DEST_FOLDER /E /LEV:1 /XF *
```

Options:

- `/E` Copy Subfolders, including Empty Subfolders
- `/LEV:1` Only copy the top n LEVels of the source tree.
- `/XF *` eXclude Files matching given names/paths/wildcards.

Source: http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html

Comment: I can confirm that /LEV:2 was required to copy one level of folders within the cited folder. /LEV:1 appears to be the folder cited itself.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to Steven's answer, it seems that if you want all the folders within folder X, you'll need to specify folder X as the source and then use `/LEV:2`, not `/LEV:1` (I'm guessing `/LEV:1` is just folder X). This is what worked for me just now.

(Would've added this as a comment in reply to Steven's answer, but I don't have the privileges (low reputation).

Answer (score 0):

Using a command line, if you want to copy just empty folders, that is creating the folders on a new location say somewhere on c:...:

```
set newlocation=c:\...
@for /f "tokens=3,4" %i in ('dir') do @if "%i" equ "<DIR>" if "%j" neq "." if "%j" neq ".." mkdir %newlocation%\%j
```

If you want to go one level deep, it's to repeat the for loop once again:

```
@for /f "tokens=3,4" %i in ('dir') do @if "%i" equ "<DIR>" if "%j" neq "." if "%j" neq ".." mkdir %newlocation%\%j && for /f "tokens=3,4" %u in ('dir %j') do @if "%u" equ "<DIR>" if "%v" neq "." if "%v" neq ".." mkdir %newlocation%\%j\%v
```

Note that if you want to put this into a batch file, replace all `%` by `%%`.